# chemical equilibrium reaction for burned gases in engine

Tags: equilibrium

I do not understand how equation(3) occurs.(taken from the book Internal Combustion Engines by John B.Heywood)
$$ $$
Consider a reactive mixture of ideal gases. The reactant species $M_a,M_b$ etc.and the product species $M_l,M_m$ etc. are related by the general reaction whose stoichiometry is given by:
$$\upsilon _aM_a+\upsilon _bM_b+...=\upsilon _lM_l+\upsilon _mM_m+...$$
$$ $$

This can be otherwise written as:
$$ \sum_{i}\upsilon _iM_i=0$$
where the $\upsilon _i$ are the stoichiometric coefficients and by convention are positive for the product species and negative for the reactant species.

Let $\delta n_a$ of $M_a$ react with $\delta n_b$ of $M_b$,etc. and produce $\delta n_l$ of $M_l$,$\delta n_m$ of $M_m$,etc..

***These amounts are in proportion,given by the equation (3):***

(3) $$\delta n_i=\upsilon _i\delta n$$

1.*Does $\delta n$ here signify 'extent of reaction'?*

2.*I would eventually like to use the number of moles of each species in expressing the chemical potential,with the gibbs free energy already known. But,the part I don't understant is equation 3. What does the author mean by proportional? Could you give a example?*

Gibbs free energy is given as:
$$(\Delta G)_(pressure,temper_)=\sum_{i}\mu _i\delta n_i$$

which by equation(3) can be re-written as(WHY??):

$$(\Delta G)_(pressure,temper_)=\sum_{i}\mu _i\nu _i\delta n$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simpler than it might look. As a random example:

$$\ce{3A + 2B->2C + 4D}$$

If I were to ask you how much of $\ce{D}$ would be produced after $5\  mol$ of $\ce{B}$ were consumed, then you would immediately answer $10\  mol$ "due to the stoichiometry". In more elaborate terms, for a $\Delta n_B=n_B^{after}-n_B^{before}=-5\ mol$, one has $\Delta n_D=n_D^{after}-n_D^{before}=+10\ mol$. Any infinitesimal change in quantity of any species $i$ ($\delta n_i$) is accompanied by a shift in the quantities of all other species precisely determined by the stoichiometry of the reaction (the stoichiometric coefficients, $v_i$), such that $\frac{\delta n_i}{v_i}$ is constant for all species $i$. For the above reaction, $-\frac{\delta n_A}{3}=-\frac{\delta n_B}{2}=\frac{\delta n_C}{2}=\frac{\delta n_D}{4}$. The ratio $\frac{\delta n_i}{v_i}$ is defined as $\delta n$, and you can think of it as a counter for "how many times the reaction happened" ($\delta n>0$ if left to right, $\delta n<0$ if right to left).

$\delta n$ is a general change in amount of substances, but the particular case where changes are calculated relative to the equilibrium condition ($\Delta n=n^{equilibrium}-n^{before}$), then it represents the extent of reaction.